# How to sort a list with specified property and sort order

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list of java beans, now I want to sort them with specified property and sort order
(the property and sort order are input parameters), like this:

```
class Person{
    private String userName;
    private Integer age;
    private String address; 

    public void sort(List<Person> ps, String property, String sortOrder)
    {
        // How to use the property and sortOrder??
        Collections.sort(ps);
    }
}
```

What is the best way of writing the `sortList()` method?
actually I have one way to do this. I can write two static properties for Person. then I set these two properties before sorting:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    private String userName;
    private Integer age;
    private String address;
    public static String sortProperty;
    public static String sortOrder;

    public void sort(List<Person> ps, String property, String sortOrder)
    {
        Person.sortProperty=property;
        Person.sortOrder=sortOrder;

        Collections.sort(ps);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o)
    {
        // find the property with Person.sortProperty using reflection
        // then sort the property
    }
}
```

This is not a good solution. Could anyone give me some suggestion? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this makes sense for you. Use `final` keyword to avoid creating `static` variable for passing sort order. Also changed it to boolean for easy access. Below code is just for illustration.

```
public static void sort(List<Person> ps, String property, final boolean asc) {

  if (property.equals("userName")) {
    Collections.sort(ps, new Comparator<Person>() {

        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            // pls use appropriate compareTo I always get confused
            // which one to call when it is asc or desc.
            if (asc)
                return o1.getUserName().compareTo(o2.getUserName());
            else
                return o2.getUserName().compareTo(o1.getUserName());
        }
    });
  }

  if (property.equals("age")) {
    Collections.sort(ps, new Comparator<Person>() {

        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {

            if (asc)
                return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
            else
                return o2.getAge().compareTo(o1.getAge());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Good alternative to avoid using reflection. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a `Comparator` and use it like this.
`Collections.sort(ps, myComparator)`

Inside the comparator you can just retrieve property and sortOrder from person and compare with these variable

Comment: Where can i retrieve the property and sortOrder? There should be somewhere to set these two variables, where?

Comment: A Comparator is an interface, you need to implement the compare method, which will contain Person as arguments, you can check gurung's answer, he wrote a example for you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(ps, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {           
        int result = 0;
        if(sortProperty.equals("userName")) {
            result = p1.userName.compareTo(p2.userName);
        } else if(//...
        //determine how based on sortOrder here
        //e.g.
        if(sortOrder.equals("ascending") {
            return result;
        } else {
            return (result * (-1));
        }
    }
});
```

Note: `property` and `sortOrder` need to be declared `final`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Write three Comparators.  They could be static fields.  E.g.

public static final Comparator COMPARE_BY_NAME =    (your code here)
And similar for COMPARE_BY_AGE   etc.

Pass them to the standard Java sort() methods.

Answer (score 0):

To make the sorting as generic extended method of a list you can use below code:

```
public static List<T> SortList<T>(this List<T> list, string sortDirection, string sortExpression)
    {
        if (sortDirection.ToLower() == "sorting_asc")
        {
            return (from n in list
                    orderby GetDynamicSortProperty(n, sortExpression) ascending
                    select n
                   ).ToList();
        }
        else if (sortDirection.ToLower() == "sorting_desc")
        {
            return (from n in list
                    orderby GetDynamicSortProperty(n, sortExpression) descending
                    select n
                   ).ToList();

        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }

    public static object GetDynamicSortProperty(object item, string propName)
    {
        //Use reflection to get order type
        return item.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(item, null);
    }
```

Calling:

```
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        var sortedEmployees = employees.SortList(sortedorder, sortedcolumn);
```